# Unable to SSH/gcloud into default Google Deep Learning VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, gcloud, google-dl-platform

I created a new Google Deep Learning VM keeping all the defaults except for asking no GPU:

[image]

The VM instance was successfully launched:

[image]

But I cannot SSH into it:

[image]

Same issue when attempting to use with `gcloud` (using the command provided when clicking on the instance's arrow down button at the right of `SSH`):

[image]

```
ssh: connect to host 34.105.108.43 port 22: Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

[image]

Why?

---

VM instance details:

[image]

Comment: Does your account have permission to access the SSH? If not then try [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions)

Comment: Just a heads up if you're planning on using JupyterLab to train a model you can access it under the AI Notebooks but if you do not allow access then you will not be able to do things like mount your bucket, send files locally to your VM instance, etc.

Comment: @yuRa Thanks "Does your account have permission to access the SSH?" -> how can one check whether one has permission to access the SSH?

Comment: You can head over to IAM & Admin. There it will show the members that have access to the project.

Comment: You can also just follow [this guide to connect to the VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#windows_cli)

Comment: @yuRa Thanks, is "Enable connecting to serial ports" required to SSH into the instance?

Comment: Yes you would need that.

Comment: @yuRa thanks, this appears to be the root of the problem then. I'll try to figure out why it's greyed out, perhaps some restrictions of my organization. I'll keep you posted when I find out.

Comment: No problem I will add my answer.

Comment: @yuRa Thanks, isn't Enable connecting to serial ports" required only for Windows instances, and not Linux?

Comment: I did it on Linux before, honestly the documentation for GCP can be quite conflicting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an off topic *usage* question and not a software development question

Comment: @ChrisStratton 100% on topic, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "if your question generally covers [...] software tools commonly used by programmers [...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: Google cloud is a *hosting provider* not a software *development tool*.  Your issue concerns basic everyday adminstrator configuration of a cloud host and/or its firewall, *not* software development, even if it needs to be accomplished so that you can *do* some development.

Comment: @ChrisStratton gcloud is a program, see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud. The quote says "software tools commonly used by programmers", not "software development tool".

Comment: All off-topic *usage* questions concern "a program" - that's an utterly absurd argument.  Your issue is with system adminstration; an on-topic GCP question would concern interaction of a program *you were writing* with a GPC API or unique capability, not generic **system adminstration** such as this in the context of GCP.

Comment: @ChrisStratton not all programs are "commonly used by programmers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to the VM Instance you will have to follow the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#windows_cli) from GCP and then set up the role with the necessary authorization under IAM & Admin.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the browser-based SSH client and browser-based gcloud client were disabled by my organization, this is why I couldn't access the VM. The reason I was given is that to allow browser-based SSH, one would have to expose the VMs to the entire web, because Google does not provide a list of the IPs they use for browser-based SSH.

So instead one can SSH into a GCP VM via one's local SSH client by first uploading one's SSH key using the GCP web console. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#linux-macos ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200920001819/https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced)) for the documentation on how to use one's local SSH client with GCP.

---

Since the documentation can be a bit tedious to parse, here are the commands I run on my local Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x64 to upload my SSH key and connect to the VM:

If you haven't installed `gcloud` yet:

```
# https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#linux (<- go there to get the latest gcloud URL to download via curl):
sudo apt-get install -y curl
curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-310.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xvf google-cloud-sdk-310.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
```

Once `gcloud` is installed:

```
# Connect to gcloud
gcloud auth login
# Retrieve one's GCP "username"
gcloud compute os-login describe-profile
# The output will be "name: '[some large number, which is the username]'"
# Create a new SSH key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/gcp001 -C USERNAME
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/gcp001
# if you want to view the public key: nano ~/.ssh/gcp001.pub
gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file ~/.ssh/gcp001.pub
gcloud compute ssh --project PROJECT_ID --zone ZONE VM_NAME
# Note that PROJECT_ID can be viewed when running `gcloud auth login`, 
# which will output "Your current project has been set to: [PROJECT_ID]".
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

- `sudo gcloud compute config-ssh`
- `gcloud auth login`

Login to your Gmail account. Accept access of Google Cloud.

Later set project if not yet done:

- `gcloud config set project YOU-PROJECT-ID`

Run `gcloud compute ssh` with all you need.

If you still have a problem, please remove this:

- `rm .ssh/google_compute_engine`

Run `gcloud compute ssh` with all you need **again** and the issue should be solved!